# What do humans do in Manvantaras 2-6?

Tags: human

It seems humans are completely missing in any story in Manvantaras 2-6, despite humans known to be there as Svārociṣa, Uttama, Tāmasa, Raivata, and Cākṣuṣa Manu are present. Does anyone have a counterexample of humans involved in stories or a reason for the missing time of humanity?

Comment: why do u think so,,there were many examples like Priyavrata, Rishabhadeva and Bharata (after whom our country is named) etc..  ~ https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp058.htm

Comment: @YDS They all happen in either Manvantara 1 or 7 as far as I know

Comment: @YDS Bharata had to be in Manvantara 7 as he is in the lunar dynasty which began in Manvantara 7, as it is after Vaivasvata https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_dynasty#/media/File:LUNAR_DYNASTY_(Chandravamsha).png

Comment: this is diff Bharata (Dusyannta's son) the earlier was Rishabhdeva's son..bdw from 2-6 also we hv kings like Chaitra, Kimpurusha (from 2nd), Aja, Parashuchi, Divya (from 3rd)..Markandeya purana lists devas, indra, saptrishis and kings of each manvantra....

Comment: @YDS If you have proof they happened in Manvantaras 2-6 post an answer